# Trying to align input forms in html/css

Tags: html, css

Do you know by any chance how to align input fields for expiry date and security code inside div in my case. I've tried everything but can't fix this problem

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style=" width:37%; margin-left:115px;background-color:#212361; height:500px;">
    <form class="pay-form">

        <h2 style="color:#707070">Invoice</h1>
        <div class="container-wrapper" style=" margin-left:45px;">
            <img src="slike/payment/american_express.png" style="border-radius : 90%; height:80px; width:22%;">
            <img src="slike/payment/jcb.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
            <img src="slike/payment/master_card.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
            <img src="slike/payment/visa.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:90px; width:22%;">   
        </div>

        <p style="color:#707070">Card number</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="card_number" required>
        <p style="color:#707070">Name on card</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:80%;" name="name_on_card" required>
  
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Expiry date</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="expiry date" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Security code</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="security_code" required>
        </div>
            
        <p style="color:#707070">Email</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="email" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button>GO</button>
            
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide CSS of the code

Comment: FYI - you have a  typo in your header... you're using an opening `h2` tag but a closing `h1`.

Comment: are you looking for what  `input {box-sizing:border-box;}` would do ?

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it' solves your problem !

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using Bootstrap in your code. However, you only wrap those two fields with class `.col-md-6` and that class will add a margin of 15px to right and left.
What you need to do is to wrap all other fields above and below `Expiry date` and `Security code` with `.col-md-12` class

```
<div class="container-fluid" style=" width:37%; margin-left:115px;background-color:#212361; height:500px;">
    <form class="pay-form">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 style="color:#707070">Invoice</h1>
            <div class="container-wrapper" style=" margin-left:45px;">
                <img src="slike/payment/american_express.png" style="border-radius : 90%; height:80px; width:22%;">
                <img src="slike/payment/jcb.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
                <img src="slike/payment/master_card.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
                <img src="slike/payment/visa.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:90px; width:22%;">   
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p style="color:#707070">Card number</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="card_number" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p style="color:#707070">Name on card</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:80%;" name="name_on_card" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Expiry date</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="expiry date" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Security code</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="security_code" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p style="color:#707070">Email</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button>GO</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### **This is what you want** [**CODEPEN DEMO**](https://codepen.io/I-am-Ironman/pen/jRgGWE)

```
<div class="container-fluid" style=" width:37%; margin-left:115px;background-color:#212361; height:500px;">
  <form class="pay-form">
    <h2 style="color:#707070">Invoice</h2>
      <div class="container-wrapper" style=" margin-left:45px;">
        <img src="slike/payment/american_express.png" style="border-radius : 90%; height:80px; width:22%;">
        <img src="slike/payment/jcb.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
        <img src="slike/payment/master_card.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:100px; width:22%;">
        <img src="slike/payment/visa.png" style="border-radius : 50%; height:90px; width:22%;">
      </div>
      <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:80%">
        <p style="color:#707070">Card number</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="card_number" required>
        <p style="color:#707070">Name on card</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="name_on_card" required>

        <div class="row">
          <span class="col-6 mr-0">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Expiry date</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="expiry date" required>
          </span>
          <span class="col-6 ml-0">
            <p style="color:#707070;">Security code</p>
            <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="security_code" required>
         </span>
        </div>
        <p style="color:#707070">Email</p>
        <input type="text" style="width:100%" name="email" required>
        <br><br>
        <button>GO</button>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```